# Does the final executable use symbol tables to check variable scope

Tags: linker, compiler-construction, executable, elf

I'm trying to understand the linking and loading phases in depth.

When a translation unit is compiled / assembled into a single object file, i understand that it creates a symbol table of every variable / function found.

If a variable has only file scope by using the static keyword for example, it will be marked as local in the symbol table.

However, when the linker produces the final executable file, is there a final symbol table there with every single entry encountered for all files?

I was confused because if we have a variable declared as static meaning only file scope within one file, when this variable is encountered every time in the executable, does the compiler have to reference the final symbol table to see its actual scope, or does it generate special code for it?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: It depends: some symbols can be kept for debugging purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a translation unit is compiled / assembled into a single object file, i understand that it creates a symbol table of every variable / function found.

That is *mostly* accurate: local (aka stack, aka automatic storage duration) variables are never put into the symbol table (except when using ancient debugging formats, such as [STABS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabs)).

You don't need to take my word for it: this is trivial to observe:

```
$ cat foo.c
int a_common_global;
int a_global = 42;
static int a_static = 43;

static int static_fn()
{
  return 44;
}

int global_fn()
{
  int a_local = static_fn();
  static int a_function_static = 1;
  return a_local + a_static + a_function_static;
}

$ gcc -c foo.c
$ readelf -Ws foo.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 14 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 a_static
     6: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 static_fn
     7: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 a_function_static.1800
     8: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     9: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
    10: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
    11: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM a_common_global
    12: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 a_global
    13: 000000000000000b    34 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 global_fn
```

There are a few things worth noting here:

1. `a_local` does not appear in the symbol table
2. `a_function_static` got "random" number appended to its name. This is so `a_function_static` in a different function will not collide.
3. `a_static` and `static_fn` have `LOCAL` linkage

Note also that while `a_static` and `static_fn` appear in the symbol table, this is done *only* to assist debugging. The local symbols are not used by subsequent link, and can be safely removed.

After running `strip --strip-unneeded foo.o`:

```
$ readelf -Ws foo.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     7: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM a_common_global
     8: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 a_global
     9: 000000000000000b    34 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 global_fn
```

> when the linker produces the final executable file, is there a final symbol table there with every single entry encountered for all files?

Yes. Adding `main.c` like so:

```
$ cat main.c
extern int global_fn();

extern int a_global;
int a_common_global = 23;
int main()
{
  return global_fn() + a_common_global + a_global;
}

$ gcc -c main.c foo.c
$ gcc main.o foo.o
$ readelf -Ws a.out

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 69 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
```

... I omit un-interesting entries (there are many).

```
 0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND

34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.c
35: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
36: 0000000000201030     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 a_static
37: 000000000000061c    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 static_fn
38: 0000000000201034     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 a_function_static.1800

50: 0000000000000627    34 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 global_fn

63: 00000000000005fa    34 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
64: 000000000020102c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 a_global
```

> I was confused because if we have a variable declared as static meaning only file scope within one file, when this variable is encountered every time in the executable, does the compiler have to reference the final symbol table to see its actual scope, or does it generate special code for it?

At link stage, the compiler is (usually) not invoked at all. And the linker doesn't (doesn't need to) pay any attention to `LOCAL` symbols.

In general, the linker only does two things:

1. Resolve undefined references (such as reference to `global_fn` and `a_global` from `main.o`) to their definitions (here in `foo.o`) and
2. Apply relocations.

Applying relocations for `a_static` and `a_function_static` in `foo.o` doesn't actually need their names; only their offsets within the `.data` section, as this output should make clear:

```
$ objdump -dr foo.o
foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64   
Disassembly of section .text:
...
000000000000000b <global_fn>:
   b:   55                      push   %rbp
   c:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   f:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  13:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  18:   e8 e3 ff ff ff          callq  0 <static_fn>
  1d:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  20:   8b 15 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%edx        # 26 <global_fn+0x1b>
            22: R_X86_64_PC32   .data
  26:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  29:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  2b:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 31 <global_fn+0x26>
            2d: R_X86_64_PC32   .data+0x4
  31:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  33:   c9                      leaveq
  34:   c3                      retq
```

Note how relocations at offset `0x22` and `0x2d` don't say anything about the names (`a_static` and `a_function_static.1800` respectively).

Comment: Ok Thank you for that

Comment: What are the values exactly in the symbol tables, and why is .data in the disassembly section of .text? What is happening exactly at 22 and 2d ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

> When a translation unit is compiled / assembled into a single object file, i understand that it creates a symbol table of every variable / function found.

The object file will only have information about global symbols referenced and defined by the compilation unit.

> However, when the linker produces the final executable file, is there a final symbol table there with every single entry encountered for all files?

An executable file will on include universal symbols (those that need to be defined in loadable libraries). A loadable library will only include universal symbols but it may define those symbols as well as reference them.

If you define a static variable XYX that name disappears when you compile.

If you define a global function (that is not exported in a loadable library), that name disappears when you link.

The one bit of oversimplification I have made here is that compilers and linkers support the OPTIONAL inclusion of debugging information that may describe all symbols encountered in processing.

Debugging information about a symbol must include information about the modules that defined the symbol.

The debugging information is usually completely separate within the object and executable files from the information needed to run or link those files. In fact, debugging information can usually be stripped out easily from those file.

Comment: "The object file will only have information about global symbols" -- that is *also* incorrect (at least on most ELF platforms and for most compilers).

Comment: I have been reading that the object file will contain a symbol table of all symbols found, local and global

Comment: If will IF debugging information is included. For actual linking, it does not need local variables.